# Emit event while require statement fails

Tags: solidity, events, logs, modifiers, require

I would like to be able to log a result of a condition:

```
if(time > 5) {
    emit Result("time is larger than 5");
} else {
    emit Result("time is less than 5");
}
```

This will work just fine, but when using a `require` statement:

```
  require(time > 5);
  emit Result("time is larger than 5");
```

I can only log the event in case the `require` succeeds.

In case the `require` appears in a modifier:

```
modifier OnlyLargerThan5() {
  require(time > 5);
  emit Result("time is larger than 5");
  _;
}
```

Is there a way to log both cases (Larger > 5 > Less) other then the `if..else` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if...else` statement is a completely valid option, and is one I would suggest.

Something you can do, if desired, is include a message in the require statement. This would not be an event, but would looks something like this:

```
require(time > 5, "time is less than 5");
emit Result("time is larger than 5");
```

Comment: Is the message from the require statement logged to the blockchain and can be traced (like an event)?

Comment: I do not believe so. The most logical solution would be to use the `if...else` statement. You will not be able to log any data if the transaction reverts.

Comment: So it seems. Problem is that my function (that emits the events) gets called by another contract which in turn can revert.. so nothing can guarantee that I'll actually emit my events.

Comment: Correct. One of the biggest discussions in Solidity relates to external calls to other contracts. You can write a perfect function, but if there is another contract that is relying on it or it is relying on, then there is now a possibility of failure/attack vector.